# How do a track validation loss in TensorBoard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am training a model in TensorFlow. Periodically during training, I evaluate the model on a validation set. I'd like to write a summary of the training procedure so that [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) displays a plot of the validation set loss so that I can see it go down with more training iterations. (Or jump back up if I start to overfit.)

I already have a global iteration variable as part of my summary. I'm thinking of creating a scalar summary `validation_loss` variable in the model graph that isn't connected to anything, but to which I periodically assign a variable to from my training loop.

Is this a good strategy? Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in TensorFlow?

(The specific project I'm working on is the [TensorFlow RNN Language Model](https://github.com/wpm/tfrnnlm), which is a generalization of the [RNN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) in the TensorFlow documentation.)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the idiomatic solution is to merge all summaries (in case loss is not your only summary) before creating a `tf.train.SummaryWriter` separately for your training and validation set. Then use the `add_summary` Op on the validation SummaryWriter for each (periodic) iteration.

Comment: I'm using `tf.train.SummaryWriter` and will merge all summaries once I have more than one. The part that's got me confused is that the summary writer writes values of tensors within the graph, but total validation set loss is not recorded in a single tensor in the graph. Instead is is calculated in a loop over the individual validation set batches.